# How do I add <span> tags as a child of only <li>'s with a specific class (pls see example)

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="selected" href="#">One</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to use jQuery to find the `li a` with the class of `selected`, and add a span as a child of the `li`. So it ends up looking like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="selected" href="#">One</a>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think I have to use `.find` but I am not sure how to put it together. If anyone can give me a hand, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery("a.selected").parent().append("<span class="arrow"></span>")
```

Broken down it becomes:

`jQuery("a.selected")`: All the `<a>` tags that have the `"selected"` class.
`.parent()`: Find its parent element.
`.append("<span class="arrow"></span>")`: Add the span on the end.

I would also suggest you check the jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("li.selected").append($("<span/>",{class:'arrow'}));
```

or you can use `after`

```
$("li.selected").after($("<span/>",{class:'arrow'}));
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HsjPS/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do what you need:

`$("a.selected").parent().append("<span class='arrow'>")`